# How do I reward diversity in the prediction results of my model?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, loss-functions

For example, say I have two models that try to predict some labels `y`.

```
y = [-1, 0, 1]
```

model 1 prediction:

```
x = [0, 0, 0]
rmse: 1
mae: 1
```

model 2 prediction:

```
x = [-2, 0, 2]
rmse: 1
mae: 1
```

Both models have the same rmse and mae but clearly model 2 is better because it conveys more information about whether or not the target variable is positive or negative. What loss function can I use to reward diversity in the prediction of model 2?

Comment: I don't know of a pre-existing one, but should be easy enough to make your own? Just convert each prediction/actual to "pos", "neg", or "zero" and then do equivalent to mae

Comment: Hm, I should have been more clear in my question - the outputs are continuous. It's not just {-1, 0, 1}. It could be -14.3289 etc. and I would still like the granularity of a continuous prediction.

Comment: Agree with @Dave. Both models are equally bad/good. And your loss functions show that. If your outputs are continuous, surely the best model is the one which produces the closest prediction, irrespective of whether it's positive or negative?

Comment: I did post a comment saying that I’m not convinced the second one is better. Thinking about it more, diversity of predictions is one measure of added value, so there’s more to it than just RMSE.

Comment: Assume `y = [1 2 3]`, your first model gives `x = [2 2 2]` and your second model gives `x = [0 2 4]`. Would you still say that the second model is *clearly* better? Yes, it has a higher correlation with the actual, but it's also more variable, and higher variability in predictions can be problematic in itself.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I would say that is better, yes. Because the second model conveys more information than the first model. The second model gives me relative measurements - It tells me that the first variable is smaller than the mean and that the last variable is larger than the mean. The first model conveys only the mean.

Comment: seems that you are interested in ranking i.e. that your predictions will be ranked similar to the true values. For this you can you ranking losses like NDCG. If you are also interested in the magnitude you can use a weighted average between MSE and NDCG, but you will have to decide which part is more important to you.